# Get index as int in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which is indexed by strings. Let's say my index looks like `df.index = ['AA','AB','AC',...]` and I want to access `df.loc['AC':'AE']`, which works well.

Is there any way to get the position of these indices, giving me `['AC':'AE'] => [2,3,4]`? I know there is `df.index.get_loc('AC') => 2` but this works only for single values and not for lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to extract the integer range:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(7), index=['AA','AB','AC','AD','AE','AF','AG'])

def return_index(df, a, b):
    col_map = df.index.get_loc
    return np.arange(col_map(a), col_map(b)+1)

res = return_index(df, 'AC', 'AE')

print(res)

array([2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5,6,7,8, 10]}, index=['AA','AB','AC','AD','AE'])

pos = list(range(df.index.get_loc('AC'), df.index.get_loc('AE') + 1))
print (pos)
[2, 3, 4]
```

Another solutions with [`Index.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html):

```
pos = list(range(df.index.searchsorted('AC'), df.index.searchsorted('AE') + 1))
print (pos)
[2, 3, 4]
```

---

```
a = df.index.searchsorted(['AC', 'AE'])
pos = list(range(a[0], a[1] + 1))
print (pos)
[2, 3, 4]
```